# is it legitimate to have an non-free app to show ads as well?

Tags: iphone, model

on iPhone App Store I see two categories of apps - not free w/ no ads and free with ads. Is it legitimate to have an app that not free but will show ads as well? Is there any problem with that model?

Comment: There's no "right" answer to this question, it's subjective; SO isn't set up for subjective questions. For some, a paid app with ads is fine. For others, a paid app with ads is a rip-off.

Comment: That's a great way to tell your paying customers they are nothing more to you than dollar bills, not the best message to send imho.

Comment: Your question is about to be closed as "not constructive." Which is too bad, it should be "off-topic" and migrated to http://programmers.stackexchange.com. You might consider reposting there when this question is closed.

Comment: Thanks for taking the right actions. I got the answer anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't. If they pay, they expect no ads and it to be feature complete bar in app purchases. If you need the income, bump up the price. Adding ads will just annoy your users.

Answer (score 3):

You can still have ads in an app that is paid however, people generally purchase apps thinking they won't contain ads and by including ads, people will be inclined not to purchase the app and leave bad reviews and ask for money back and therefore, it's generally a bad idea to include ads in a paid app...